# System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found': Error

Tags: visual-studio-app-center, sqlite-net

Running sqlite-net (v1.6.292) in latest xamarin forms (v4.5.0.282) application along side Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics and Crashes (v2.6.4) with no issues. I upgraded Microsoft.AppCenter.* from 2.6.4 to 3.0.0 today and now sqlite-net crashes on first execution of CreateTable such as database.CreateTable

(); with the below error message.
System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'System.String SQLitePCL.raw.sqlite3_column_name(SQLitePCL.sqlite3_stmt, Int32)'.'

Has anyone else seen this error or might know what the fix for this issue might be? I am suspecting Microsoft.Appceneter.* is updating something with sqlite that sqlite-net is not compatible with?
I have rolled back my upgrade until I can determine the cause.

Orgbrat

Answer (score 4):

[App Center 3.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AppCenter/3.0.0) uses SQLitePCLRaw 2.0, which is not compatible with sqlite-net v1.6.292. As an option, you can update sqlite-net to 1.7.302-beta to resolve this version conflict.

You can find detailed changelog for this version [on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-sdk-dotnet/releases/tag/3.0.0).